# QnA Maker My Knowledge Bases drop down contains disabled items

Tags: azure, azure-qna-maker

I was given access to a customer's Azure tenant and QnA Maker but cannot select the tenant in the My Knowledge Bases view. Chrome shows the items as red/disabled and IE strikes them out. Either way, cannot select them. Everyone believes the right access has been provided so we are at a loss.

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the page where you are not able to select the tenant? Also, can you elaborate on what steps the customer has followed to provide you access to their tenant and qnamaker(it should be done via Azure [RBAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal))? Are you using the same email id to login to qnamaker which was used to grant access on Azure?

Comment: This is not a qnamaker issue, but got to do with Azure resources. I would suggest you open an issue on https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/create-ticket/

Comment: Hmm not really it’s a drop down with the names of all my customers. It’s the My Knowledge Bases page. The items have a css class called color-red and are disabled. So something in the qnamaker UI is disabling them. I’m sure there’s logic somewhere in the code that says disable the items in the drop down in condition x. I have complete access to the azure tenant and contributor access to the entire resource group which includes the qnamaker instance. Same email id.

Comment: I understand it may have to do with Azure but it would surely assist us in better diagnosing this issue if we knew why it’s disabled. All of our team was provided access by the client in the same way. Most of us can access it. Two of us ran into this issue. We are all at a loss.

Comment: Modified post with pic. Blurred out client names. You can see there's two red items. Those are the tenants that are disabled for whatever reason. I'm trying to understand what that reason is.

Comment: Do you notice any error or exceptions on the Chrome Dev Tools console when the page is loaded? Also, can you try using the [Tenants-List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/tenants/list) and QnAMaker [Get Knowledgebase for User](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5a93fcf85b4ccd136866eb37/operations/knowledgebases_getknowledgebasesforuser/console) APIs and confirm if you have the tenant and knowledgebase accessible to your account?

Comment: Also, opening an issue on [azure support](azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/create-ticket ) as well on [GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues) would help you gain more traction and resolve the issue faster.

Answer (score 0):

Were you able to resolve the issue? I'm currently experiencing the same for a tenant I used to be able to access before. I think it may have to do with MFA being activated on my guest account recently, but unfortunately I haven't found a way to be able to select the tenant again.

Comment: We also have this same issue and it also started after MFA was activated.  Did you find a fix?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure this works for you, but try logging on to https://portal.azure.com using your account and switch to the subscription that is giving you issues. It may require you to reauthenticate using MFA. After I've done this I was able to select the subscription in the QnAMaker.

Answer (score 0):

The fix that worked for me was to ensure that my default directory was one that has 2FA enabled for my user.  This was the fix recommended by Microsoft support.

1) Close QnAMaker
2) Open the Azure Portal
3) Click your Avatar/user in the top right
4) Click Switch Directory
5) In the "Set your default directory" dropdown, select a dirctory in which 2FA is enabled for your user.  (Microsoft recommended selecting the directory that owns the QnAMaker resources).
6) Open QnAMaker and you should see your knowlegebases.